# Bucle infinito comprobando usuarios

Tags: java, bucles

Tengo un problema con mi código de Java que es el siguiente: el metodo Comprobar, debe verificar que el username pedido al usuario sea igual al username que está en el arreglo de la clase Verify.

Al ejecutar el programa, funciona bien por una vez, aparece el mensaje que deseo y posteriormente vuelve a pedir el username, pero al hacer esto por segunda vez se queda en un bucle de "El usuario no es correcto".

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Verify {
    Datos obj = new Datos();
    String username[] = {"Camilo","Cristiano","Messi","Lucas","Juan","Joe"};
    String password[] = {"12","34","56","78","09","10"};
    boolean usernameCorrect = false;
    public void Comprobar(){
        for(int i=0;i<username.length;i++){
            while(usernameCorrect == false){
                if(obj.username1.equals(username[i])){
                    usernameCorrect = true;
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El usuario no es correcto");
                    obj.pedirUser();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: por qué no pruebas reiniciar la variable `usernameCorrect` adentro del método... para que se reinicie con cada iteracion

Answer (score 1):

> Años que no uso Java; pero te aporto con la lógica de lo que veo ocurre.

Tu variable `usernameCorrect` la inicias en `false`.

Cuando entra al ciclo `for` ocurre lo siguiente:

Entras al `while` evaluando `usernameCorrect == false`.

Tu variable `i` siempre es cero ya que nunca la incrementas.

Por lo anterior siempre esta evaluando a `obj.username1.equals(username[i])`. *Es decir, si `obj.username1.equals("Camilo")`*.

Por el mensaje que indicas esta saliendo quiere decir que la condición no se cumple nunca.

Puede tu `while` este mal ubicado o está sobrando; revisa tu proceso para quitarlo o hacer el ajuste que corresponda al comportamiento esperado.

Comment: Hola RobertoLeOr, la variable **i**, se incrementa dentro del for, eso deja a tu respuesta muy mal parada, te sugiero que la edites para evitar recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Saludos @MarcePuente; sin duda la variable `i` debe estar controlando el recorrido del array mientras se incrementa en el `for`; pero si notas detenidamente (al iniciarse el `for`)`usernameCorrect` entra en `false` (se cumple en primer momento para entrar) se evalúa el `if`/`else` sin embargo, sigue dentro del `while` quedando sin cambios la variable `i` no sale al `for` por eso el **bucle infinito**.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás uniendo mal las dos tareas.

Por un lado necesitas verificar que el usuario esté en el arreglo y por otro seguir pidiéndolo hasta que sea válido.

Es una buena idea crear una función para la primera y otra para la segunda. Así:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Verify {
    Datos obj = new Datos();
    String username[] = {"Camilo","Cristiano","Messi","Lucas","Juan","Joe"};
    String password[] = {"12","34","56","78","09","10"};

    bool ComprobarUsuario(String usuario){
        for (String _usuario : usuarios)
            if (usuario.equals(_usuario))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void PedirUsuarioCorrecto(){
        while (!ComprobarUsuario(obj.username1)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario no es correcto");
            obj.pedirUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Por si acaso, `!condicion` es equivalente a `condicion == false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void comprobar() {

     // eliminé el while, ya que no tiene sentido su uso
     // pedimos el usuario
  String user = obj.username1;

     // recorremos los usuarios registrados
  for( int i = 0; i < username.length; i++ ) {

        // si hay coincidencia, cambiamos a true y salimos del for
     if( user.equals( username[ i ] ) ) {
        usernameCorrect = true;
        break;
     }
  }

     // imprimimos el mensaje correpondiente
  if( ! usernameCorrect ) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "El usuario no es correcto" );
     return;
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Hola macho!!!" );
```

}

Se pueden hacer varias modificaciones, por ejemplo, que el método **comprobar** devuelva un booleano, o bien que reciba parámetros para volver a utilizarlo para verificar el password.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto. A mi me ha funcionado bien:

class Verify {

```
Datos obj = new Datos();
String username[] = {"Camilo","Cristiano","Messi","Lucas","Juan","Joe"};
String password[] = {"12","34","56","78","09","10"};
boolean usernameCorrect = false;

public void Comprobar(){
    
    while(!usernameCorrect) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < username.length; i++) 
            if (obj.username1.equals(username[i])) 
                usernameCorrect = true;
        
        if (!usernameCorrect) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El usuario no es correcto");
            obj.pedirUser();
        }
    }
}
```

}